# Ember.js: how to save a model

Tags: model, save, ember.js, ember-data

From the ember docs its clear you should be able to save a dirty model

```
var m = App.MyModel.find(10) ;
...
m.set("firstName", "John") ;
m.get("isDirty") ; // --> true
```

Now, I don't know how to save, things like

```
m.save() ;
App.MyModel.save(m) ;
//etc
```

do not work. Any suggestions ?

CHeers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT: This is  now out of date with Ember Data 1.0 beta and onwards, please refer to Bart's answer**

If you are using Ember-Data, you need to call `commit()` on the model's transaction.

```
m.get('transaction').commit()
```

or if you want to save every dirty object in your app

```
m.get('store').commit()
```

Comment: there is still one weird thing, if I create a new model and try to save it like: var p = App.Post.createRecord({firstName: "bla", lastName: "blabla"}); p.get("transaction").commit(); The request that this call creates is a GET to http://localhost/~ME/posts/

Comment: That's really weird, have you customized the adapter at all? It should really be a POST request to `/posts`

Comment: yep, I've extended the RESTAdapter, because I had to set the 'namespace': App.Adapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({namespace: '~User123'}); Is there something that can be done to fix this, and if so, is this somewhere documented ?

Comment: No, you would have had to do some serious rewriting of the adapter to get your POST requests sent as GET requests, are you sure you don't have some middleware or something that might be converting them?

Comment: My mistake, I do see the POST now, for some reason it didn't show up in my console, only the GET which is done after the POST. So the commit() does a POST and then a GET, why ?

Answer (score 51):

The accepted answer is no longer valid since the release of Ember Data 1.0 (beta at the time of writing). Saving is much easier and more intuitive with Ember Data (1.0).

```
var person = this.store.createRecord('person');
person.set('frist_name', 'John');
person.set('last_name', 'Doe');
person.save();
```

It is also good to know that a `save` call returns a promise, which is resolved when the server returns a response.

```
person.save().then(function() {
  // SUCCESS
}, function() {
  // FAILURE
});
```