# Saving data captured from form rendered in a modal component

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, zurb-foundation

**Ember** - v1.7.0

**Ember Data** - v1.0.0-beta.10

---

I created a modal component using zurb foundation 5 CSS framework reveal features, though all works well, am unable to save data captured from the form in controller save action.

Controller which handles on save button execution

```
App.PersonModalController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    actions: {
        close: function() {
            return this.send( 'closeModal' );
        },

        save:function() {
            this.get('model').save();
        }
    }
});
```

The issue am facing is that the `this.get('model').save()` is not working and data is not been posted to restful backend.

Am not sure exactly how to go about storing the data captured from the form, when I `console.log( this.get('model') );` it appears to be a proper model object with all the bells and whistles.

I tried obtaining the store to add model to it but that doesn't work too.

**A. Addendum**

After searching around I came across a number of Stack Overflow questions relating to `this.get('model').save()` it appears it doesn't quite work as expect, perhaps based on context.

[difference-between-model-save-versus-model-getstore-commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17309934/difference-between-model-save-versus-model-getstore-commit)
[ember-js-how-to-save-a-model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14455570/ember-js-how-to-save-a-model)
[save-record-of-model-is-not-working-in-ember-data-1-0-0-beta-3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19402943/save-record-of-model-is-not-working-in-ember-data-1-0-0-beta-3)

When I change code to the following:

```
App.PersonModalController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    actions: {
        close: function() {
            return this.send( 'closeModal' );
        },

        save:function() {
            var person = this.store.createRecord('person',{firstName:firstName,lastName:lastName});
            person.save();
        }
    }
});
```

<strike>It POSTs data correctly to back-end and saves, I however believe there must be a better way, cause if you have a form with say 50 fields, you won't want to manually set each attribute.</strike>

After careful inspection, though posting occurs, the data posted is empty.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to continue your save method as in Bart's answer to the ember-js-how-to-save-a-model question.

```
person.save().then(function() {
  // SUCCESS
}, function() {
  // FAILURE
});
```

and in those methods I would console.log() the results.

I would imagine it has something to do with the promise aspect of the save functionality.